# “Don’t confine yourself”

Tags: word-usage, ellipsis

From what I see in dictionaries, with the word “confine,” generally “to” is used as in “confine somebody/something to something.” I wonder if it is okay to use the word “confine” without “to something.” For example, can we say this sentence?

- *”Don’t confine yourself.”*

The context of the sentence is, let’s say I have a friend who goes outside very rarely and who is very asocial, and I want him to leave his house/apartment more. So I say the example sentence above to him like in, “Don’t confine yourself. Go outside more.” Would it be grammatically wrong? Do I have to say, *“Don’t confine yourself to home/your apartment”* instead of it?

Comment: Not the "confine" is wrong, but I wonder if I wouldn't say "don't lock yourself in" instead.

Comment: There are definitely more idiomatic ways to say this, maybe something like "Don't shut yourself up" or (less forcefully) "Don't stay indoors all the time". I don't think there's a clear favorite among them, but "confine" is more a word for fine writing than speech. But it's grammatically OK.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine. The rest of the sentence is implicit, and context dependent.

If I'm advising a student and say "don't confine yourself" I might mean "don't confine yourself to courses where you're sure to get an A."

Comment: Thanks. You mean it is fine for the context I provided too, right?

Comment: Yes. But see @PPH 's comment on the question.